# Is it possible to customize site status messages?

Tags: status-messages

There are various types, like "Error, status" and they show up after creating content, or when triggered by a rule.

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a new type, such as "Dev" and have it's visibility limited to certain roles, like administrator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [status type can be customised](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7#comment-23023) so you're covered with that one.

Assuming you're setting messages using drupal_set_message, you could check if the message should be set based on the status of the user. To make it a bit cleaner, you might want to write a module so you can set a specific permission to show this message to certain roles.

Comment: Spot on! I don't suppose I'd be fortunate enough for there to be a contributed module which allows one to add such things without hacking core?

Answer (score 1):

There's a module for D6 that gives you a hook and a class for matching/editing messages displayed to the user - http://drupal.org/project/messages_alter